# How to insert string from Richtextbox into XML File in C# Winform

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, savefiledialog

I am putting xml code into a `RichTextBox` and user can make changes here when the program is running. I want to save the content of the `RichTextBox` inside xml-file, during its creation.

Note:
I am already creating an xml file. I want to save the content of the `RichTextBox` into the xml-file, during its creation.

```
saveFileDialog1.Filter = "XML files(.xml)|*.xml|all Files(*.*)|*.*";
saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();


if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
{
    gridView1.AddNewRow();
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

    XmlElement anaeleman = document.CreateElement("onbase-certificate");

    //i want to do it here
    TextWriter yaz = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialog1.FileName,true);
    yaz.Write(f2.richTextBox1.Text);
    yaz.Close();

    XmlElement alteleman = document.CreateElement("licences");
    for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.DataRowCount); i++)
            {

                XmlElement elemanlar = document.CreateElement("licence");

                XmlElement eleman = document.CreateElement("name");
                eleman.InnerText = "![CDATA[" + gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "productname").ToString() + "]";
                elemanlar.AppendChild(eleman);

                eleman = document.CreateElement("code");
                eleman.SetAttribute("sig", "1");
                eleman.InnerText = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "producttype").ToString();
                elemanlar.AppendChild(eleman);

                eleman = document.CreateElement("count");
                eleman.InnerText = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "count").ToString();
                eleman.SetAttribute("sig", "1");
                elemanlar.AppendChild(eleman);

                if (gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "pilotdate").ToString() != "")
                {
                    eleman = document.CreateElement("pilotdate");
                    eleman.InnerText = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "pilotdate").ToString();
                    eleman.SetAttribute("sig", "1");
                    elemanlar.AppendChild(eleman);
                }

                alteleman.AppendChild(elemanlar);

            }
    //anaeleman.AppendChild(alteleman);

    anaeleman.AppendChild(alteleman);

    document.AppendChild(anaeleman);

    document.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
}
```

Comment: why do you write richtextbox content to saveFileDialog1.FileName with yaz.Write(...) and then you rewrite it with document.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName) ?

Comment: Because i can not insert  yaz.Write(...)  XMLelement so triyed to save the codes afte creating the xml file

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using XmlDocument you can use plain `StringBuilder`.

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendLine("<onbase-certificate>");
builder.AppendLine(f2.richTextBox1.Text);

builder.AppendLine("<licenses>");
for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.DataRowCount); i++)
        {

            builder.AppendLine("<license>");
            builder.AppendLine("<name>![CDATA[" + gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "productname").ToString() + "]</name>");

           builder.AppendLine("<code sig=\"1\">");
           builder.AppendLine(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "count").ToString(););
           builder.AppendLine("</code>");

            // ...


           builder.AppendLine("</license>");

        }
builder.AppendLine("</licenses>");

builder.AppendLine("</onbase-certificate>");
File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, builder.ToString());
```

Comment: thank you but i also record information from the DataControl so i have to use XmlDocument

Comment: Is the DataControl bound to the xmlDocument? Using the StringBuilder you can add as many information as you like, nested as well.

Comment: i edited my code : inserted datagrid parts. Please look at

Comment: It's really a bad idea to build the XML manually when you can use a XML library just as easily. For one, `XmlDocument` will handle all special characters escaping and maybe formating. This is specially important to avoid "XML injection" (for a lack of a better term).

Comment: So? What's your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do. Do you want to save the text from richtextbox to xml element anaeleman? If yes, have you tried this:?

```
anaeleman.InnerText = f2.richTextBox1.Text
```

Comment: No. I want to save the text from Richtextbox to xml file(existing file).